# How to add XAMPP to my desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, operating-system, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on my Ubuntu O.S but I want to add a GUI icon to my desktop? I followed an old post which generated the GUI but it doesn't launch when I click it. Can anyone provide a detailed step for Ubuntu 20.04?